# SQL Server 2016: Use FOR XML and STUFF with Multiple Join Query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016, stuff

I have a query made for reporting purposes to list out employers that have not submitted quarterly reports and to list out the quarters that haven't been submitted. This is my query:

```
with employerIds as (select distinct Employerid
                from employerTransaction),
quarters as (select distinct QId
                    from employerTransaction)
select ei.EmployerId, e.EmployerName, q.QId
from employerIds as ei
cross join quarters as q
left join employerTransaction as et
        on et.EmployerId = ei.EmployerId
        and et.QId = q.QId
join employer as e
        on e.EmployerId = ei.EmployerId
where et.employerid is null
group by ei.employerid, q.QId
order by ei.EmployerId, q.QId
```

The following is the result of the query:

```
    EmployerId   EmployerName                 QId
    1            Potato Inc                   20193
    1            Potato Inc                   20202
    1            Potato Inc                   20203
    2            Donuts LLC                   20202
    2            Donuts LLC                   20203
    3            Pineapple Logistics          20191
    3            Pineapple Logistics          20192
    3            Pineapple Logistics          20193
    3            Pineapple Logistics          20194
```

What I would like is to combine the QId column into one row for each EmployerId like this:

```
     EmployerId   EmployerName                 QId
     1            Potato Inc                   20193, 20202, 20203
     2            Donuts LLC                   20202, 20203
     3            Pineapple Logistics          20191, 20192, 20193, 20194
```

I'm using Sql Server 2016 so unfortunately I'm unable to take advantage of `string_agg()` and would have to utilize `FOR XML` and `stuff()`. I am not sure how to use `stuff()` on a query that has multiple joins. Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: You do not use the STUFF function for that. You use a FOR XML (sub)query for that. The STUFF function is only used to beautify the end result by removing a leading (or trailing) separator.

Answer (score 1):

This is `for xml path` clause doing the trick. `stuff` just strips the leading ','

```
with sampledata as (
   -- your original query here
)
select EmployerId, EmployerName,
   stuff( (select ','+ cast(t2.Qid as varchar(5))
          from sampledata t2
          where t2.EmployerId = t1.EmployerId and t2.EmployerName = t1.EmployerName
          for xml path ('')), 1, 1,'') qids
from sampledata t1
group by EmployerId, EmployerName
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=4162c6cde903949e6b954f062f307372)

Returns

```
EmployerId  EmployerName    qids
1   Potato Inc  20193,20202,20203
2   Donuts LLC  20202,20203
3   Pineapple Logistics 20191,20192,20193,20194
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The Qid are aggregating, but I am seeing duplicate Employerid's returning when running the query. For example, in the second example output I provided in my question, Potato inc returns three times, Donut LLC, returns twice, and Pineapple logistics returns four times etc.

Comment: `...for xml path ('')).value('text()', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1....`

Comment: @BGonzaga, .. [my fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=4162c6cde903949e6b954f062f307372) uses exactly your sample data. I see no duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Solution

```
Select  ei.EmployerId, 
        e.EmployerName ,
        ISNULL(STUFF((Select Distinct ', ' + Cast(QId  As Varchar(500))
                        From employerTransaction As Q
                        Where  et.QId = q.QId
                        FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, ''),'-') As [NewQID]
From employerIds As ei
Left Join employerTransaction as et on et.EmployerId = ei.EmployerId and et.QId = q.QId
Join employer as e on e.EmployerId = ei.EmployerId
Where et.employerid is null
Group By ei.employerid, e.EmployerName
```

Comment: If you use a comma and a space (`', '`) as the separator, the separator is 2 characters long. You should reflect that in the STUFF function's third argument as well. That should be a 2 instead of a 1. Otherwise, the resulting values in the `[NewQID]` column will start with a space.